# Move location of special character

Tags: r

I have an entire vector of strings with the only special symbol in them being "-"

To be clear a sample string is like 23 C-Exam

I'd like to change it 23-C Exam

I essentially want R to find the location of "-" and move it 2 spaces back.

I feel this is a really simple task although I cant figure out how.

Assume that whenever R finds "-" , two spaces back is whitespace just like the example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`regex` attempt:

```
x <- c("23 C-Exam","45 D-Exam")
#[1] "23 C-Exam" "45 D-Exam"
sub(".(.)-", "-\\1 ", x)
#[1] "23-C Exam" "45-D Exam"
```

Find a character `.`, before a character `(.)`, followed by a literal dash `-`.
Replace with a literal dash `-`, the saved character from above `\\1`, and overwrite the dash with a space

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a sleek way of doing this with regular expressions, but one approach is to simply splice together the various pieces of the desired output.  First, I find the index in the string containing the `-`, and then I use `substr()` to piece together the output.

```
pos <- regexpr("-", "23 C-Exam")
x <- "23 C-Exam"

x <- paste0(substr(x, 1, pos-3),
            "-",
            substr(x, pos-1, pos-1),
            " ",
            substr(x, pos+1, nchar(x)))

> x
[1] "23-C Exam"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `chartr`

```
chartr(" -", "- ", x)
#[1] "23-C Exam" "45-D Exam"
```

#### data

```
x <- c("23 C-Exam","45 D-Exam")
```